# Java Recursion Scope Variable

Tags: java, recursion, scope, global-variables, local-variables

I was looking for a program to generate balanced parentheses for given n pairs. Link: https://leetcode.com/problems/generate-parentheses/
for the solution, I found that in the below code

```java
public void P(List<String> list, int openB, int closeB, String output, int n) {
    if (output.length() == 2 * n) {
      list.add(output);
      return;
    }
    if (openB < n) {
      String op1 = output + "(";
           // openB=openB + 1; 
           //P(list, openB, closeB, op1, n); using this is giving different output.
      P(list, openB + 1, closeB, op1, n);
    }
    if (closeB < openB) {
      String op2 = output + ")";

      P(list, openB, closeB + 1, op2, n);
    }
}
```

Here using
`openB=openB+1;` is giving a different result **as compared to passing the value in the method itself**

Answer (score 1):

Well, when you pass `openB + 1` as an argument, it doesn't change local `openB` variable. On the other hand, when you do `openB = openB + 1` it does change its value, and, since we use it later in method (in `closeB < openB` branch), program could behave differently.